# iOS static library contains no symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I made a static library for iOS and when I try to use it in my Unity build I get errors like this.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_pk_addTest", referenced from:
  _PocketKaldiNative_pk_addTest_m19215872 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
 (maybe you meant: _PocketKaldiNative_pk_addTest_m19215872)
```

I used lipo -info on the static library to confirm it built an arm64 library.
Then I used ar -t to confirm that it was including the .o files. The library also 385MBs.
Finally, and here's the weird part, I used nm -debug-syms and got nothing back. I also tried -extern-only, -demangle, -undefined-only and still nothing.

How is it that I'm building this .a incorrectly to have no symbols?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience `nm` does not show any symbols for static libraries compiled with bitcode enabled, which is the default with Xcode nowadays. If you turn that off (set the 'Enable bitcode' option in the build settings to 'No') then you should be able to see the symbol table.